# Query to find all messages a user is participating in

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a messaging system. A user can start a conversation by messaging multiple recipients who in turn can reply back.

I want to find all conversations a user is participating in. Ie. conversations where they have either authored a message or were a recipient of a message in the conversation.

Currently my models looks like this

```
# Message
belongs_to :conversation
belongs_to:user #author
has_many :receipts
has_many :recipients, :through => :receipts

# Conversation
has_many :messages

# User
has_many :receipts
has_many :incoming_messages, through: :receipts, :class => 'Message'

# Receipt
belongs_to :message
belongs_to :user
```

I want to create a scope on Conversation to achive something like this

```
Conversation.involving(user)
```

Not sure how to write the scope / sql for this. It feels like I need the equivalent of an OR statement in there.

ie. in PSEUDO CODE

```
conversations where (messages.recipient_ids include user.id OR  messages.user_id == user.id)
```

I'm assuming ive modeled the system correctly. If not any better schema suggestions would also be greatly appreciated.

Can anyone help with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Conversation.includes(messages: :receipts).where(["messages.user_id = :user_id OR receipts.user_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id])
```

This is doing the where clauses on the user_id foreign keys so that you don't have to figure out what table aliases ActiveRecord would assign to the users table (since it would be joined twice).

Comment: Excellent, can I ask why you chose includes over join?

Comment: Habit, mostly. If you don't need any of the data from those tables for your view, using joins should be faster.